# problem with sending bytes from client to server using TCP

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock

My send() and recv() looks like this:

```
int Send(const char* buffer, int size)
{
    cout << "SIZE: " << size << endl;
    int offset;
    while(offset < size)
    {
        int n = ::send(getSocket(), buffer + offset, size - offset, 0);
        if(n == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            break;
        }
        offset += n;
        if(offset != size)
        {
            Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    return offset;
}

int Recv(char* buffer, int size)
{
    int n = ::recv(getSocket(), buffer, size, 0);
    if(n == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error receiving data" << endl;
    }
    if(n == 0)
    {
        cout << "Remote host closed connection" << endl;
    }
    return n;
}
```

But my output show kind of many bytes sent that seems strange to me:

```
Received from client: 669
Sent to web server: 3990336
```

So it should supose to sent 669 bytes, so from where did it get 3990336 ? It is some kind of error or ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to initialize `offset` with zero. Otherwise it could be any random value.
2. You do not need `Sleep` as `send` call is blocking.
3. Buffer that you are sending could be split. So if you send, for example, 2K buffer, you could get it in two parts - 1.5K and 0.5K, so you have to perform multiple reads on a client side. [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) is usually set to 1500 bytes.

Comment: @vBx, you should compile with warnings, such as `-Wuninitialized` (GCC).

Answer (score 5):

Did you notice that `int offset;` is not initialize ?

Comment: actually i didnt,that was my problem,i don;t know how i missed that

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's just your (stripped down?) example code, but you never actually initialize `offset`. It might have any value, e.g. -5000 and will cause the loop to send 5669 bytes.